# Change dynamically number of rows on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I need your help guys.
I use a **textarea** that automatically expands by changing the number of rows.
In my project, the page does not reload and stays as it is after submitting the form. I need to change dynamically the number of rows (2) on submit.
Also one can send the form by Enter. So I need to change the number of rows after pushing a button or hitting the Enter key.
I've coded a rough sketch of the form that I have in my project so that you could test it: https://codepen.io/C3La-NS/pen/NagZbr

```
<form id="NewMessage">
  <textarea id="shoutbox-comment" data-min-rows="2"></textarea>
  <button id="send_message" type="submit" onclick="chatSubmit();">send</button>
</form>
```

JS:

```
    // auto-resizing textarea
const textarea = document.getElementById("shoutbox-comment");

textarea.addEventListener("input", function() {
  this.rows = 2; // Erm...
  this.rows = countRows(this.scrollHeight);
});

function countRows(scrollHeight) {
  return Math.floor(scrollHeight / 20); // 20px = line-height: 1.25rem
}

// submit by Enter
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#shoutbox-comment").on("keypress", function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 10 || event.keyCode == 13) {
      event.preventDefault();
      chatSubmit();
    }
  });
});

// submit FORM
function chatSubmit() {
  $("#NewMessage").submit();
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: You actually want to empty the textarea and remove the rows you added?

Comment: Yes, if it is going to minify textarea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery submit accept as parameter a callback that is triggered before submit so, you can do:

```
$("#NewMessage").submit(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('#shoutbox-comment').attr('rows', 2);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just couple of changes in your script:

```js
const textarea = $("#shoutbox-comment");
const minRows = textarea.data('minRows');

textarea.on("input", function(e) {
    this.rows = 1; // Erm...
    this.rows = countRows(this.scrollHeight);
});

function countRows(scrollHeight) {
    var toReturn = Math.floor(scrollHeight / 20); // 20px = line-height: 1.25rem
    return toReturn > minRows ? toReturn : minRows;
}

// submit by Enter
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#shoutbox-comment").on("input", function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 10 || e.keyCode == 13) {
          e.preventDefault();
          chatSubmit();
        }
    });
});

// submit FORM
function chatSubmit() {
    // Send the message via AJAX;
    textarea.val('').trigger('input');
    return false;
}
```

```css
#shoutbox-comment {
    width: 220px;
    outline: none;
    resize: none;
    line-height: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="NewMessage">
    <textarea id="shoutbox-comment" data-min-rows="2"></textarea>
    <button id="send_message" type="submit" onclick="chatSubmit();">send</button>
</form>
```

I've also included `data-min-rows` attribute inside the script.
Also on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/skobaljic/pen/aLwgPX).